# How to connect watson assisstant v2 with Amazon skill kit in Aws Lambda?

Tags: node.js, promise, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, watson-assistant

Hello I want to connect my watson assisstant with an alexa device, 
for this I need Amazon development skill kit and AWS lambda. But i can't connect watson because i got problem with my promises and i can't see the logs of my code in the amazon developer console. And my assistant work on nodeJs application.

There is the headers of my watson :

```
const assistant = new AssistantV2({
  version: '2019-02-28',
  iam_apikey: 'apiSecretKey',
  url: 'https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api'
});

const assistant_id = "assistantIDSecret" ;
```

There is some codes that i tried :

```
const MyNameIsIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'SearchIntent';
  },
   async handle(handlerInput) {


      assistant.createSession({
        assistant_id: assistant_id
      })
          .then(res => {
              session_id = res.session_id;
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
          });
        assistant.message({
            assistant_id: assistant_id,
            session_id: session_id,
            input: {
                'message_type': 'text',
                'text': "hello"
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
                 speechText = res.output.generic.response.text;
            })
            .catch(err => {
              speechText = err;
      });


    }, function(err){
      speechText = "Problem with Api call";
    });

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

I tried to replace then, catch by an await:

```
 try{

      let res = await assistant.createSession({
        assistant_id: assistant_id
      });

      session_id = res.session_id;

      let message = await assistant.message({
        assistant_id: assistant_id,
        session_id: session_id,
        input: {
          'message_type': 'text',
          'text': "hello"
        }

      });
      speechText = message.output.generic.response.text;

    }catch(err){
      speechText = err;
    }
```

The results of speechText should give me "Good day to you" it's a response that comes from Watson.but now Alexa says "Sorry, I can't understand the command. Please say again."

Do you have an others ways to try this? thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have managed to call out to Watson Assistant, and if the response configured in your dialog node was "Good day to you" -which is what you have received, then that connection is working. If I remember right however the response that Alexa is expecting is a JSON object, not a string. So you need to format the response to meet Alexa's needs. 
A quick look at this site: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html 
indicates that the following is a good example the required response json packet.

```
{
  "version": "string",
  "sessionAttributes": {
      "key": "value"
  },
  "response": {
      "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "text": "Plain text string to speak",
      "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ENQUEUED"      
  },
  "reprompt": {
      "outputSpeech": {
         "type": "PlainText",
         "text": "Plain text string to speak",
         "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ENQUEUED"             
      }
  },
  "shouldEndSession": true
 }
}
```

Note. I cannot confirm as I have never had an Alexa Skill taken to production ( only built them as demo's under the development environment, and shared with a limited few). But I have been informed that Amazon are not happy for their skills to off load work to Watson. Which is a shame.